# Variable referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file from which I am reading a few values and calculating the mean and standard deviation. i am using pandas to work with with my csv files. To calculate mean I am doing this:

```
def mean(filename):
    csva = pd.read_csv(filename, header =0)
    ratios = np.array(csva["ratio"])
    return ratios[~np.isnan(ratios)].mean()
```

This works fine. However , there are a few files (2 /10 files) where the header `ratio` is replaced by `zr2212` . If I try the above function on those files I get `KeyError : u'no item named zr2212'`. So I modified my code to this:

```
def mean(filename):
        csva = pd.read_csv(filename, header =0)
        try:
            ratios = np.array(csva["ratio"])
        except KeyError as e:
            if e == "no item named ratio":
                ratios = np.array(csva["zr2212"]
        return ratios[~np.isnan(ratios)].mean()
```

However I get the `UnoundLocalError: local variable 'ratios' referenced before assignment` error at the `return` statement. I dont get it why do i get an error there

Comment: you have a syntax error in this line `ratios = np.array(csva["zr2212"]` you omit `)` is it by copy past?

Answer (score 4):

```
if e == "no item named ratio":
```

This is false. `e` is an exception, not a string.
Take out the `if` line and it should work.

Comment: That was the issue. However I remember a basic python class where we were taught something like this thats why I used it

Comment: Actually, he's probably looking for `e.msg` or `e.message`, or even maybe just `str(e)`.

Comment: You can check the `message` field in the exception if you want, but I don't think there's any need.

Comment: It can make good sense to have an `if` like this (if you get it right). But then you have to do decide what should happen in the `else` case. Do you want to `raise` to propagate the exception? Or `raise` a different one? Or set `ratios` to an empty series? Or `return` some default value? You have to do _something_, or you're going to end up with exactly what you see: `ratios` doesn't exist, and you try to use it anyway.